# What does your ideal web development (ASP.NET) environment consist of?

Tags: development-environment

I start at a new client on Monday.  They’re just beginning to do web development (ASP.NET) and I’m going to help them with setting up a proper development environment.

I don’t think I’ll have a say on what type of machines the developers will be using, so this is more of a backend scenario.

So far the main things I’ve come up with include:

- Versioning control system (source control).
- Bug Database
- Doc Repo / Project Management / Tasks
- (They are currently using Base Camp by 37 signals, which is a good sign to me.)*
- Dev / QA / Staging / Build servers (web, db)

So far this is what I have come up with.  I don’t know what budget they have right now, but in your ideal development environment, what else would you recommend that I propose?
Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what, but I get a gramatical error while parsing your question ;-)

Comment: lol yeah after i published it, I thought, wow that question is a bit off.  my bad :)

Comment: slightly better, and damnit I have no problem ending a sentence with a preposition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, there is no ultimate answer for this. Because each developer has their own opinion - what software they use for VCS, Bug Tracking, etc...

And here is my opinion :)

Ideal for Microsoft Technologies is TFS ([Team Foundation Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/teamsystem/default.aspx)), which has all the features you want.

And here my list in case you don't want TFS:

**Version control system**

- [SVN](http://subversion.tigris.org/)
- [Mercurial](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/)
- [GIT](http://git-scm.com/)

**Bug Database / Project Management / Tasks**

- [JIRA](http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/)
- [FogBugz](http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBugz/)

**Developers environment**

- Dual screen
- Powerful PC
- Quality chair
- Whiteboard
- Free coffee
- This is all very cheap if you compare it to their salary for six months

Comment: I'm definitely going to recommend TFS, but not sure it's within budget.  TFS is pricey, unless they have an MSDN subscription.

Answer (score 2):

You said you won't have input on the machines, but I'd put dual monitors pretty high on the list as far as productivity goes for web development or just computer use in general.

Answer (score 0):

Development machine: Visual Studio 2008 + VisualSVN/TortoiseSVN + Resharper

Buildserver: Teamcity

LAN testing server: Webserver with build by buildserver + DB with daily copy of live

QA/Staging depends on the project size.

Comment: It's going to be a pretty large application, high visibility.

I think it will be only be Visual Studio 2005 at this point.

I love Tortoise/SVN.  I'm praying they don't say they want to use Sourcesafe